# Using a variable from another class C#, Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I'm trying to use the int buttonCount to be added to listbox on another page. I used  public static int buttonCount = 15; to make my butttonCount int available on the MainPage.xaml.cs, but when I try to use it on highScore.xaml.cs it seems to not show up. My name space is Potato_v2 and class is just the name of the page. Here's some of my code for gamePage.

```
    public static int buttonCount = 0;
    string stringButtonCount = "";
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int count = 15;



    void countDownTimerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    txtCountdown.Text = count + " Seconds Remaining";


        if (count > 0)
        {
        count--;
        }
        if (count == 0)
        {
            countDownTimer.Stop();
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/highScore.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            count = 15;
            buttonCount = 0;
            stringButtonCount = "";
        }

   }
```

Code for MainPage: Can't get the first line to go down for some reason.

private void newToDoAddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

```
    {
        ToDoItem newToDo = new ToDoItem { ItemName = newToDoTextBox.Text };
        ToDoItems.Add(buttonCount);
        toDoDB.ToDoItems.InsertOnSubmit(newToDo);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access a variable outside its class without Class name (static member) or instance. So this line:

```
ToDoItems.Add(buttonCount);
```

Should be:

```
ToDoItems.Add(ToDoItem.buttonCount);
```

Comment: That's what I did first, I saw somewhere that is not the right way to do it. It keeps saying I don't have access to the namespace.

Comment: @user2823955, it shouldn't. Clean, Rebuild your solution. If you can access your class `ToDoItem` in code then there shouldn't be any problem in accessing its `int` property.